# Why is the `object_id` of a `Fixnum` an odd number?

Tags: ruby

`object_id` of a `Fixnum` is an odd number:

```
i=0; i += 1 while i.object_id.odd?
# ^CIRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!
i # => 495394962
```

while it seems that the `object_id` of any other object is an even number (`Bignum` included):

```
{}.object_id # => 70230978908220
true.object_id # => 20
false.object_id # => 0
nil.object_id # => 8
/regexp/.object_id # => 70230978711620
:symbol.object_id # => 391528
{/regexp/mou => Struct.new(:hello)}.object_id # => 70230987100840
```

Does this have something to do with some obscure optimization within the Ruby interpreter?

Comment: @CarySwoveland  `0.object_id` yields  `1` (in my irb session). Maybe this is something related to the ruby version I'm using.

Comment: Symbols and floats (except possibly really large ones) seem to have even object id's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done so that integers do not take up all the room for other objects. In Ruby all other Objects have even object_id's, they go in between. The integer object_id's are very easily converted to their value:   the last bit (always a 1) is chopped off.

Integers are a bit fake objects, they are no more than an id and a shared list of methods.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know how that relates to other immediate objects, like symbols and floats, are handled?

Comment: @CarySwoveland No. I don't even know what immediate objects are. nil, true and false seem to have fixed id's.

Comment: Note that this is an internal private implementation detail of YARV. Other Ruby implementations may or may not follow the same pattern. All that is guaranteed by Ruby is 1) the same object has the same `object_id` during its lifetime and 2) at no time do two different objects have the same `object_id` at the same time. (Note, however, that two different objects may have the same `object_id` at different times, i.e. `object_id`s may be recycled). Everything else is up to the implementor. The specific case here is that YARV simply uses the memory address as the `object_id` and uses a tagged …

Comment: … pointer representation for `Fixnum`s. I explained tagged pointer representation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3774467/2988

Comment: @JörgWMittag I did read your explanation at least a year ago. I've read a many of your answers and learnt a lot. Thanks.