# What does 31 bit tagged integer mean?

Tags: integer

Is there a difference between 31 bit tagged integer and 32 bit integer?
Is 31 bit tagged used for "signed" integers and 32 bit for unsigned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is an int in OCaml only 31 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773985/why-is-an-int-in-ocaml-only-31-bits)